# warning: control reaches end of non-void function C++ when already having a return 0 in an if statement

Tags: c++, oop, recursion

I have my return statement in an if statement and if I add a return 0; at the end it will mess up the functionality of the function. What to do?

```
int EfficientTruckloads::numTrucks(int numCrates, int loadSize){
    if (numCrates == 0){
        return noTrucks;
    }
    if (numCrates == 1 || numCrates <= loadSize ){

        return noTrucks;
    }else { 
        if (numCrates %2 == 0){
            noTrucks++;
            noTrucks++;
            numTrucks(numCrates/2,loadSize);
        }else if (numCrates %2 != 0){
            noTrucks++;
            noTrucks++;
            numTrucks((numCrates + 1)/2,loadSize);
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the cases of `numCrates %2 == 0` and `numCrates %2 != 0`, there is no `return` statement. Also, you are calling `numTrucks` recursively, but then discarding the result of that call. Did you perhaps mean to `return` the same?

Comment: *"it will mess up the functionality of the function"* -- it is tough to come up with an answer that does not mess up the functionality of the function when we don't know what that functionality is. Could you add the function's requirements? In particular, what is it supposed to do when `numCrates > loadSize`? (Currently, it does nothing productive.)

Comment: Will a while loop not suffice here ?

Comment: Writing this function recursively is a bad idea. But if you're committed to it, just change both occurrences of the recursive call `numTrucks(whatever);` to `return numTrucks(whatever);`.

Comment: Just a tip: `noTrucks++; noTrucks++;` is usually written `noTrucks += 2;`.